# QR algorithm for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of large symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am trying to write a [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) in Python for eigenvectors and eigenvalues finding for large symmetric matrices,

My initial thought was to use [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) with a Wilkinson shift when I ran it on an $800 \times 800$ matrix is did not converge within reasonable time. I tested the algorithm on smaller matrices and it did converge and the results were correct

What else can I apply to reduce the convergence time
and how can I use the fact that the given matrix is symmetric to my aid?

Comment: Did you prepare the iteration by  putting your  matrix Hessenberg form ? The gain is huge, each iteration costing ony $O(n^2)$ instead of $O(n^3)$.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com may be a better home for this question

Comment: So just to understand the order of operations:
1. Convert to Hessenberg form
2. Calculate mu (Wilkinson shift)
3. Decompose to QR via householder
4. Check convergence and try again if not?

Comment: Those are the right steps, but after (4) you go back to (2), not (1), as (3) preserves Hessenberg form.

Comment: i've tried that however there are two problems
1.  The convergence time is still unreasonable
2. The use of Hessenberg form changes the eigenvectors

the obvious bigger problem is 1